# NoClassDefFoundError: javax.jmdns.JmDNS

Tags: android, jar

I am trying to jmDNS jar , but when I run my app it is throwing error like **NoClassDefFoundError**: javax.jmdns.JmDNS .

It is throwing error from this line

```
     jmdns = JmDNS.create();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your jar is included in your projects /libs directory. That is the only place that will ensure it is properly added to the jvm at runtime on device. There can be several other issues which you should used adb logcat *:D to watch the classloading to discover. Look for L errors happening before the exception itself.

Comment: Can u please tell me how to add jar to libs directory

Comment: In the project root, create a dir called 'libs' and copy the jar file to that location.

Comment: If I do like this console is showing error like .....Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

Comment: Well, there is no guarantee that your jar is compatible with android. You'll either need to track down what is causing the incompatibility or find a different mechanism to do the job.

Comment: I am trying to list all the devices connected to wireless network.I am searching in internet for the available jars but I am only getting the jmDNS. If u know any other way , please help me.....

Answer (score 0):

Download the jar file from the Maven Repository and add it to your classpath. I was having the same problem and that worked for me :)

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jmdns/jmdns/3.5.1/jmdns-3.5.1-sources.jar